# Combining XML fields of same name when Loading XML into SQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to load an xml file into an SQL table and it's working well with one exception. I have multiple fields of the same name that I want combined on load. In this case the  field. Currently, it only grabs the last instance of the redundant column name.

**My current XML has the following structure:**

```
<item>
    <name>......</name>
    <type>...</type>
    <text>some text</text>
    <text>some more text</text>
    <text>even more text</text>
</item>
```

**and here's my SQL:**

```
"LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'xml/items.xml'
INTO TABLE items
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<item>'";
```

This is what I currently get in my SQL "Text" column:

```
even more text
```

and my desired result is:

```
some textsome more textevenmoretext
```

Or better yet, if I can insert something between instances, such as a line break, that would be ideal.

Comment: Is that your full XML? Is `<item>` the root? Please post root and any namespaces it may contain. Always important for XML questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files such as your need to combine `<text>` nodes. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts using its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM TO COPY DOCUMENT AS IS -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name|type"/>
      <text>
        <xsl:for-each select="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
               <!-- ADD SPACE DELIMITER AFTER EACH ITEM EXCEPT LAST -->
               <!-- REPLACE WITH &#xa; FOR LINE BREAK ENTITY or \n -->
               <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>   
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
// LOAD XML AND XSLT 
$doc = new DOMDocument();    
$doc->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// RUN TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// OUTPUT TO CONSOLE
echo $newXML;

// OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

**Input** XML *(assumed `<items>` as root)*

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name>......</name>
        <type>...</type>
        <text>some text</text>
        <text>some more text</text>
        <text>even more text</text>
    </item>
</items>
```

**Output** XML *(use this output in `LOAD XML` command)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <name>......</name>
    <type>...</type>
    <text>some text some more text even more text</text>
  </item>
</items>
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you! My example was a relatively simplified version so I'll still have some work to do on this. A note for any like me testing this with XAMPP, you need to go into your php/php.ini and add the following "extension=php_xsl.dll" for this to work.

Comment: Glad it all worked out! You are welcome. Yes, you need to enable the php_xsl extension to use the class. Sometimes it is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

change xml `<text>` tag to `<text_one>,<text_two>,<text_three>`

```
<item>
    <name>......</name>
    <type>...</type>
    <text_one>some text</text_one>
    <text_two>some more text</text_two>
    <text_three>even more text</text_three>
</item>
```

and then by using [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) you can concatenate the text and insert it to your filed

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'xml/items.xml'  INTO TABLE 
items (@name, @type, @text_one, @text_two, @text_three)   
SET name=@name, type=@type, text= CONCAT_WS(' ',@text_one,@text_two,@text_three);
```

Comment: The issue is my current XML is thousands of lines long. Is there a forEach method that could concat all the instances of the same element name together?